APS (forge) viewer SVF2 loading throwing "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'manifest')"
Recently we have migrated from SVF to SVF2 in our APS (Forge) viewer. However, sometimes we are receiving this error while trying to load a model on the viewer:

and this error in the console:

And when we go to Otg.js (through the console error) here is when the error has been thrown:

These are the options which we pass to Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer to load SVF2 models:
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
    api: 'streamingV2_EU',
    getAccessToken,
};

And this is how we initialize the viewer:
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
    const config = {
        extensions: [
            'Autodesk.DocumentBrowser',
            'Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore',
        ],
    };

    const container = document.getElementById('viewer');

    if (container) {
        // viewer-keeps-showing-old-model
        Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS[
            'If-Modified-Since'
        ] = Date();

        const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(
            container,
            config
        );

        viewer.start();
    }
});

And this is how we load the model:
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
    'urn:' + urn,
    onDocumentLoadSuccess,
    onDocumentLoadFailure
);

const onDocumentLoadSuccess = (doc) => {
    if (doc.docRoot.data.status === 'success') {
        const geometries = doc
            .getRoot()
            .search({ type: 'geometry' });

        doc.downloadAecModelData();

        viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, geometries[index], {
            createWireframe: false,
            applyScaling: 'm',
            isAEC: true,
        })
    }
};

And this is how we create buckets, upload and translate the models:
await new BucketsApi().createBucket(
    { bucketKey, policyKey: 'persistent' },
    { xAdsRegion: 'EMEA' }, // 'Europe, the Middle East and Africa'
    oauth2Client,
    credentials
);

await new ObjectsApi().uploadResources(
    bucketKey,
    [{ objectKey, data }],
    { useAcceleration: false, minutesExpiration: 15 },
    oauth2Client,
    credentials
);

const job = {
    input: { urn },
    output: { formats: [{ type: 'svf2', views: ['2d', '3d'] }] },
};

await new DerivativesApi(undefined, 'EU').translate(
    job,
    { xAdsForce: true },
    oauth2Client,
    credentials
);

When we use api: 'derivativeV2_EU' everything seems fine, but with api: 'streamingV2_EU' sometimes we have this issue (especially our users in France).
We tested this with different browser and the result is the same.
Is there something we've missed causing this?
EDIT:
As we tested different possible causes for this issue we found that the problem with France is something other that SVF2. If we remove this part the viewer will initialize correctly:
Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS[
    'If-Modified-Since'
] = Date();


Please provide more information (either here, or via our official support channel aps.help@autodesk.com), for example, what is the document URN and viewable GUID that fails with this error? Is all your design data hosted in a single bucket?

I've also noticed a couple of discrepancies in your code snippets, for example, I believe the region for the model derivative service should be EMEA, not EU. Also, the index variable in geometries[index] doesn't seem to be defined. Has it perhaps been defined in some other part of the code that's not shared here?

Thank you Petr for your comment. Actually the result with every document URN and GUID is the same. Weirdly, it occurred only with SVF2 and especially in France.
I will check different buckets and let you know the result.

About the EMEA/EU, we followed this. It says Both EU and EMEA target EU region.

And about the index, yes it is part of the code. This code works fine with api: 'derivativeV2_EU'. I don't know why it is like this with api: 'streamingV2_EU'.

@PetrBroz We tested different buckets with both SVF and SVF2. And it seems that the error (which mentioned in the question) sometimes occurred in different regions (not only France). Can this be something about the Internet connection? Because after refreshing the viewer it would fix. However, the issue about France seems to be due to another cause. This part Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS['If-Modified-Since'] = Date(); made the viewer (in France) not to initialize. When we removed it, everything seems fine. Do you know how we can avoid this?

Yes, I can imagine the custom HTTP header interfering with the caching of the SVF2 content. Recently there's been a bug reported in that area (SVF2 caching), so this could possibly be a symptom of the same bug. For now please avoid using any custom caching logic on the viewer side.

Sure, thanks Petr. I will check the future updates on the viewer for this matter.
